# Auto-populate variables, properties, and getters / setters in PhpStorm

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

I have some classes I need to build with a large number of parameters (like 50+ in some cases). I'm using PhpStorm and was able to quickly build a list of properties like:

```
 * @property string MainKey
 * @property string MainId
 * @property string Affiliation
 * @property string ParticipantYN
```

I can then use the PhpStorm `Generate getters / setters` to create the getters and setters -- but since the class properties still don't exist, I'm getting `Field declared dynamically` warnings in the IDE.

Is there a way to auto-generate the properties? e.g.

```
 public $MainKey;
 public $MainId;
 public $Affiliation;
 public $ParticipantYN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple selection feature.

Here is how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFy1FeNnl7A&feature=youtu.be

Official blog: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/